# php and postgres reset receipt id every year

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table like:

```
id  col1  col2  receipt_id  receipt_year
1   ddd   ggg   1           2018
2   ddd   eee   2           2018
```

- **id** column is a *bigserial* and **receipt_id** is *bigint*.
- **receipt_id** and **receipt_year** is unique key
- **id** is primary key

I need to reset receipt_id for every new year like:

```
id  col1  col2  receipt_id  receipt_year
1   ddd   ggg   1           2018
2   ddd   eee   2           2018
3   lol   lpl   1           2019
```

And currently i am doing it this way :

```
$current_year = date('Y');
$sql = SELECT MAX(receipt_id) AS receipt_id FROM table WHERE receipt_year=:year;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':year' => $current_year));
$receipt_ido = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ( ! empty($receipt_ido)) {
   $receipt_id = ($receipt_ido + 1);
} else {
   $receipt_id = 1;
}
```

Is it correct way or not ?

Comment: If it works it is correct

Comment: by reset - you mean query it or effectively change the value in db?..

Comment: You mean apart from the obvious syntax error?

Comment: It is working, but i am asking is it correct way logically ?

Comment: @VaoTsun, i mean receipt id for new row that is going to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *generate* the `receipt_id` it is easy enough to do using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    id, col1, col2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY receipt_year ORDER BY id) receipt_id,
    receipt_year
FROM yourTable;
```